# How to alert when scroll page only first time using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, event-handling

How to alert when scroll page only first time using javascript ?

I want to alert only first scroll page, How can i do that ?

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var xxx;
    if (xxx === '') {
      var xxx = "test";
      var div = $("#myDiv");
      alert(div.height());
    }
  });
</script>
<DIV id="myDiv" style="height:auto; width:78;overflow:hidden"> Simple Test</DIV>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed
>   **at most once** per element per event type.

```
$(window).one("scroll", function() {
    console.log("foo");
});
```

Code snippet:

```js
$(window).one("scroll", function() {
  console.log("foo");
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>foo</div>
```

Comment: yeah.. `.one` should do the trick, didnt see OP is using jQuery so posted plain javascript answer, but this ones better

Answer (score 0):

Put you variable as global and use boolean instead of string which is a better practice when using code flags.Besides, no need to re-define you variable when setting it within the scroll function.

```js
var xxx; 

$(window).scroll(function () {

if(!xxx)
{
    xxx = true;
    var div = $("#myDiv");
    alert(div.height());
}
  });
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<DIV id="myDiv" style="height:auto; width:78;overflow:hidden"> Simple Test</DIV>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: This works but still has to compute for every scroll which can add computing load, wonder if .one also adds the same load

Answer (score 0):

```js
   onscroll = function () {
          var xxx = "test";
          var div = $("#myDiv");
          alert(div.height());
      
        onscroll = null; // remove function so wont get called next time
   };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<DIV id="myDiv" style="height:auto; width:78;overflow:hidden"> Simple Test</DIV>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will only alert on the first scroll the user makes on the page.

```js
var scrolled = false;
$(window).scroll(function() { if (scrolled == false) { alert("You Have Just Scrolled"); scrolled = true; } });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
<div>This is some text</div>
```