# is jquery .one() computing checks every event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, load

And therefore adding a bit of **computing load**?

For those of you unfamiliar with the [.one() jquery function](https://api.jquery.com/one/) it basically triggers an event just once. Such as if you wanted to add a div on the first time a page is scrolled.

To bring background to the matter, I came across this question:

[How to alert when scroll page only first time using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637069/how-to-alert-when-scroll-page-only-first-time-using-javascript/31637098#31637098)

I have been in projects where I had to add hundreds or thousands of events, so for me it’s always very important to optimize computing power, plus, I am a curious person so I just need to know.

One of the answers where the guy uses vanilla javascript is basically an endless loop where you switch a boolean on the first instance and basically have to continually enter the function to see if it has been already triggered.

```
var xxx; 

$(window).scroll(function () {

if(!xxx)
{
    xxx = true;
    var div = $("#myDiv");
    alert(div.height());
}
  });
```

My idea is that jquery being already heavy on the page it probably just performs this same action under the hood, but I would like to be completely certain as for my future implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. jQuery's `.one` works similarly to, for example:

- calling `addEventListener`, and then, in the callback, calling `removeEventListener`
- calling `addEventListener` with `{ once: true }` in the options object
- in jQuery, like calling `.on`, and then, in the callback, calling `.off`

Once the listener runs *once*, it's de-attached; no further logic takes place when the event occurs in the future, because the listener is no longer connected at all.

So `.one` is *very light* on computing resources, even if you add lots and lots of `.one`s.

You can see the source code of `one` [here](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js):

```
    if (one === 1) {
        origFn = fn;
        fn = function (event) {

            // Can use an empty set, since event contains the info
            jQuery().off(event); // <-------------------------------------------------
            return origFn.apply(this, arguments);
        };

        // Use same guid so caller can remove using origFn
        fn.guid = origFn.guid || (origFn.guid = jQuery.guid++);
    }

    return elem.each(function () {
        jQuery.event.add(this, types, fn, data, selector);
    });
```

where `jQuery()` returns a jQuery collection containing elements matching the current selector. When `one` is called, the callback is wrapped in another that calls `.off` as soon as the function is executed.

The sample code in the answer you linked to is quite inefficient, and should not be used, especially for `scroll` events, which fire very frequently.

Comment: Perfect answer, and I am glad it is as optimized as it can get too! Thanks buddy